# Mapbox GL JS compressed GeoJson files?

Tags: geojson, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, compression

I am currently using Mapbox GL JS and pull multiple GeoJson files from the style.json file. Each file in about 10MB and takes too long to load. Is there a way to compress the files and uncompressed them in Mapbox?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably converting the geojson to mbtiles. Mbtiles are more compact overall due to their protobuf format, and faster on initial load since only the visible part is requested. I'd recommend [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) for that. If you need the entire files in memory (e.g. for `querySourceFeatures`),  you might convert the geojson to topojson, or gzip the files.

Comment: thanks. If I compress the files to gzip, How do I pull them from the style.json file?

Comment: Clarification: are you grabbing geojson file/objects from a larger style.json file/object?  Are you doing this via network or filesystem?

Comment: I have style.json which pulls geojson files as sources from my server.

Comment: If they are remote HTTP sources just enable use Content Encoding on the server https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression ?

Comment: It is S3 bucket not a server. @AndrewHarvey

Comment: What about https://zanon.io/posts/serving-gzipped-files-in-amazon-s3-cloudfront?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey cloudFront wont compress the files since Mapbox is not asking for gzip